# how to separate year from MM/DD/YY format on SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, datetime

I have table with a dates formated as MM/DD/YY but it can also be like M/D/YY or MM/D/YY or M/DD/YY so I can't use substr since lengt of string changes..

For example 1/2/98 or 10/5/12 or 12/2/10 etc. etc. Since SQlite dont have any to_date function I can't use that either.

Table looks like this;

```
+-------+----------+
| NAME  |   DATE   |
+-------+----------+
| John  | 12/1/04  |
| Megan | 4/11/85  |
| Doe   | 9/18/17  |
| Smith | 10/27/10 |
+-------+----------+
```

And the expected output is this;

```
+-------+------+
| NAME  | DATE |
+-------+------+
| John  |   04 |
| Megan |   85 |
| Doe   |   17 |
| Smith |   10 |
+-------+------+
```

and I don't know how but if crazy coder can make this like

```
+-------+------+
| NAME  | DATE |
+-------+------+
| John  | 2004 |
| Megan | 1985 |
| Doe   | 2017 |
| Smith | 2010 |
+-------+------+
```

that would be so so awesome. Possible constraints are that anything <20 is 2000's and >20 is 1900's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string functions.

This gives you the first resultset:

```
select name, substr(date, -2) date from mytable
```

The second resulset requires a little conditional logic:

```
select 
    name, 
    1900 + substr(date, -2) + 100 * (0 + substr(date, -2) <= 20) date
from mytable
```

It might be easier to understand with a `case` statement:

```
select 
    name, 
    case when 0 + substr(date, -2) <= 20 
        then 2000 + substr(date, -2) 
        else 1900 + substr(date, -2) 
    end date
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=36905cdcb7e4a6140fb9827366d997d7)**:

```
name  | date
:---- | ---:
John  | 2004
Megan | 1985
Doe   | 2017
Smith | 2010
```